# How can I scale a list to the device height in landscape and not to the list content height

Tags: html, css

I have two Elements horizontally aligned, and the left one is a list. If I add some items so that the list should start scrolling, the list just grows larger then my device height is and my second content on the right side scrolls away if I scroll the list downwards. So the list is more then 100% in height... Here is some code for you :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qhylB

As I have created this code I just noticed that my both divs don't scale to 100% of the device width. Could you explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the scrollbar is on the body (or html for firefox I think). Instead you need to have the body's height fix to 100% and then move the scrollbar to the list container (33percent div):

http://codepen.io/jonigiuro/pen/JEkLH

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content33percent {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Well I just found my failure... I've added your code to my project and it was still not working, so I've deleted the jquery imports and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I modified some other stuff as well, you'll have to look at my code on codepen, here on SO I only pasted the parts to let you understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

i changed your 66% to a fixed position, now when you scroll down it looks like you are scrolling the list when you are actually scrolling the whole document, this way you can apply the scrolling over the complete document:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLzvo

```
.content66percent {
   background-color: blue;
   height: 100%;
   width: 66%;
   position: fixed;
   right: 5px;
```

also, i have removed the floating from both the 66%er and the 33%er and adjusted them a little. if you want them to touch each other, change 66% to 66.53%.